# Is there a way to limit a search by categoryId in the explore api?

Tags: foursquare

I can limit by specifying "categoryId" parameter in the /search api, but what about /explore? The "query" parameter says it also searches categories but it's picking up tips too. Completely unrelated venues show up in the results just because someone mentions part of the category name in a tip.

I can just remove results that don't match the category but I'd like for there to be another way.

The reason I want to use /explore is so I can get the rating and price, as well as a sample photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With explore, the closest approximation to a categoryId filter will be using the `section` parameter. As per our [search docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/start/search), explore and search serve different purposes, and the `section` param fits explore much better.

If you want to filter by categoryId yet still want photos and rating, I recommend calling venues/search then conducting a second [venue details](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) call to get that info.

Comment: the venue dictionaries are huge though, and doing one for each venue in each search query seems like overkill :/

Answer (score 5):

You can use `categoryId` parameter with `explore`. It's undocumented.

Comment: Well, that's the problem with undocumented features, unfortunately :(